# Line breaks not breaking using varwidth package for color background which is giving compilation error

Tags: line-breaking, varwidth

When we are using `varwidth` package and the below macro

```
\newcommand\MyCBox[1]{%
  \colorbox{red!60}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}#1\end{varwidth}}}
```

While compiling we are getting the error as `! Undefined control sequence. \dimexpr`

Please suggest me how to avoid this error.

Comment: `\dimexpr` is an e-TeX command?  This should not be a problem unless you are running a very old TeX distribution..?  As always, a real [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: With no MWE and no `.log` info, this is unclear.